# Python - delete SQLITE3 rows by data from CSV

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, dictionary

Python. I need to append and remove rows from sqlite3 database basing on data from two csv files. As for appending its all fine, i have problem with deleting.

I have csv file for deletion which looks like this:

```
hostname,shortname,env
lx1234.pl.net,lx1234,tst
sp2444445.net,sp2444445,prd
```

python looks like this:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\db.sqlite3")
cursor = conn.cursor()
[...]

######---APPEND to DB---######
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS itpassed_host (hostname, shortname, env);")
with open('C:\csv\insert.csv','rt') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    to_db = [(i['hostname'], i['shortname'], i['env']) for i in dr]

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO itpassed_host (hostname, shortname, env) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", to_db)
conn.commit()

######---DELETE from DB---######
with open('C:\csv\decom.csv','rt') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    del_db = [i['shortname'] for i in dr]
    #print(del_db)

    cursor.executemany("DELETE FROM itpassed_host WHERE shortname = ?;", (del_db,))
    conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

print(del_db) gives output:

```
['lx1234', 'sp2444445']
```

so its dictionary

it gives me error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

how to delete those rows basing on dictionary created by for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a tuple of a list, when you should be passing a list of tuples.

```
with open('C:\csv\decom.csv','rt') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    del_db = [i['cftshortname'] for i in dr]
    #print(del_db)

    del_db = [(d,) for d in del_db]
    cursor.executemany("DELETE FROM itpassed_host WHERE shortname = ?;", del_db)
    conn.commit()
```